# How Can I add currency selector on WHMCS custom page?

Tags: selector, currency, whmcs

I am trying to add a currency selector on one of my custom pages where I have displayed the product details.
I want to allow my visitor to change the default currency from this custom page and view the product pricing accordingly.

I have added this code in my custom.tpl

````
                                <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{$LANG.go}">
                                <select name="currency" onchange="submit()" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Change Currency (A$ AUD)</option>
                                    {foreach from=$currencies item=listcurr}
                                        <option value="{$listcurr.id}"{if $listcurr.id == $currency.id} selected{/if}>{$listcurr.prefix} {$listcurr.code}</option>
                                    {/foreach}
                                </select>
                            </form> ```



But it is not working, every time I select the currency from the dropdown, it refreshes the page. but nothing changes,
please guide what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance
Aqsa,
````

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. You could update your form to either:

1. Perform a GET request, and add the `currency=$id` parameter to the URL (`$id` being the ID for the currency in `tblcurrencies`.

Or

2. When your form submits, handle the form input, and set the currency in the session variable:

```
use WHMCS\Session;

Session::set('currency', $id);
```

Again, where `$id` relates to `tblcurrencies.id`.

Bare in mind that the currency cannot be changed for existing users, and it is not recommended changing their currency after they have made any transactions to avoid accounting/calculation issues.